# Python - Check for keypresses without using 100% cpu

Tags: python, multithreading, winapi, tkinter, keypress

I'm writing a GUI program in Python using Tkinter and I need a way to check if a keypress is happening without using all my cpu. Currently I'm using the threading module to start a thread that will check for the keypress without freezing the interface (Tkinter). I use win32api.GetKeyState() in a while loop inside my thread so that it constantly checks the status of the key because it needs to be able to tell if the key is being pressed even when the window doesnt have focus. The problem is the program uses 100% cpu the moment I start the thread. If I put a time.sleep() in the loop it cuts back the cpu usage dramatically BUT there is a delay between the actual keypress and the time that it knows that you are pressing a key.
Is there a way to capture a keypress the very moment it gets pressed even when the window is out of focus WITHOUT using so much cpu?

```
from Tkinter import *
import win32api

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        coords = StringVar()

        Label(master=self, textvariable=coords).pack()

        def GetCoords():
            coords.set(str(win32api.GetCursorPos()))

        root.bind_all("<Scroll_Lock>", self.GetCoords)



root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
#root.wm_iconbitmap(default='INSERT ICON HERE')
#root.wm_title("TITLE OF PROGRAM")
#app.master.maxsize(640, 480)
app.master.minsize(640, 480)
app.master.resizable(0, 0)
app.mainloop()
app.quit()
```

That script give me the following result:
AttributeError: Application instance has no attribute 'GetCoords'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to catch key events, instead of polling for the current keyboard state.

See [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) in the TkInter docs, which has a simple example that does exactly what you want (plus, it's cross-platform instead of Win32-only).

And this is generally an issue with all GUI programming (and network servers, for that matter), and the answer is always the same. You don't directly use non-blocking "check for current X status" calls usefully, with or without threads. In the main thread, you ask the event loop "call my function when X status changes", or you create a background thread and make a blocking "wait forever until X happens" call.

The Wikipedia page on [Event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) actually has a pretty good description of this.

---

Looking at your edited version, you've got a completely new problem now:

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        coords = StringVar()

        Label(master=self, textvariable=coords).pack()

        def GetCoords():
            coords.set(str(win32api.GetCursorPos()))

        root.bind_all("<Scroll_Lock>", self.GetCoords)
```

`GetCoords` is a local function defined inside `Application.__init__`. But you're trying to use it as if it were a method of `Application`. You can't do `self.GetCoords` unless `GetCoords` is a method of `self`. That's exactly what the error message `AttributeError: Application instance has no attribute 'GetCoords'` means.

But you *can* just pass the local function `GetCoords`, just by taking out the `self.` prefix. I'm not sure this will do what you think (because I'm not sure whether you can close over a `StringVar` like that or not), but… try it and see.

Alternatively, you can *make* `GetCoords` a method just by moving it out of the `def __init__` and giving it a `self` parameter. Then you *can* access `self.GetCoords`, and get a bound method, which you can pass exactly as you're trying to. However, in that case, it won't be able to access `coords` anymore, since that's a local variable inside `__init__`. To fix that, change that local variable into a member variable, by using `self.coords` everywhere in `__init__` and `GetCoords` (and anywhere else) instead of `coords`.

Comment: So I made an attempt to use a binding but I know I'm doing something wrong and I cant quite figure out what I gotta do. I used this: root.bind_all("<Scroll_Lock>", self.GetMouse) but I get this when I try to run the script: AttributeError: Application instance has no attribute 'GetMouse' I thought maybe I put it in the wrong place but I get an error no matter where i put it it seems.

Comment: First, I'm not sure why you're binding a particular keystroke to a method called `GetMouse` instead of, say, `doScrollLock`. But whatever. Did you actually create a method called `GetMouse` on your `Application` class?

Comment: @WichidNixin: OK, now I see your updated question. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me to understand what was going on, i got it working now, I just needed to remove the 'self.' from the bind_all statement